# How to convert a java file having float as return type and datatype to that of double

Tags: java

I have float calculations (Means my method returning float values or variables in my method are float type) in java, but when I am giving input of double type... all the calculations(Means return types & variables within the method) must be convert as double, how it is possible?.. but I have to use same class for both float and double inputs

Here is my method

```
public float round_a_Scale(int m, float minValue, float maxValue) {         
    if (m == 0)
        m = 10;

    float span = maxValue - minValue;
    float step = (float) Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(span / m) / 2.302585092994046)); 
    float err = m   / span * step;

    // Filter ticks to get closer to the desired count.
    if (err <= .15)
        step *= 10;
    else if (err <= .35)
        step *= 5;
    else if (err <= .75)
        step *= 2;

    return step;
}
```

In this my minvalue and maxValue are of float type, if I send double values then all the variables (span, step) and return type of my method must be changed to type double. how it is possible

Comment: If you're using primitives, append `f` or `F` to the literal value - e.g. `3.14f`.

Comment: I think that is to represent float values. But that is not my requirement

Comment: Why not just use a double and forget about it?

Comment: but i want for both float and double inputs

Answer (score 0):

e.g. you have a method like you can cast the double result to float.

But have in mind that you will lost precision.

```
float doit(double d) {
    return (float)3.4f * d;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you change your method signature to use double instead of float then you can also pass in float values by casting them to (double).

Do it this way because double is twice that range then float, so using double will make sure you will not get any overflow exceptions.

Following is pseudo code and not tested!

Using double:

```
public double compute(double value) {
    return value * (double)2;
}

double result = compute(45.5d);
```

Using Float:

```
public float compute(float value) {
    return value * (float)2;
}

double value1 = Float.MAX_VALUE;
double value2 = Float.MAX_VALUE + 1;
float resul = 0f;

// Will be called
if (value1 <= Float.MAX_VALUE) {
    result = compute((float)value1);
}

// Will not be called
if (value2 <= Float.MAX_VALUE) {
    result = compute((float)value2);
}
```

And here your Method using doubles, will except float too.

```
public double round_a_Scale(int m, double minValue, double maxValue) {
    if (m == 0)
        m = 10;

    double span = maxValue - minValue;
    double step = (double) Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(span / m) / 2.302585092994046d)); 
    double err = m  / span * step;

    // Filter ticks to get closer to the desired count.
    if (err <= .15)
        step *= 10;
    else if (err <= .35)
        step *= 5;
    else if (err <= .75)
        step *= 2;

    return step;
}
```

Or leave it as it is and check incomming double values if they not exceed Float.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: But if i send small values of range int or below than that, then memory will be wasted na

Comment: but when you pass in a double value which exceeds the range of float it will crash and makes it useless. When you want to process double values then you have to use them. Otherwise check if double value is in range of float and pass only this values to your function

Comment: Put your code in your question! And format it correctly! Will not read it in comments

Comment: Here I posted you just one method, but I have more than 10 methods like that, then what should I do,

Comment: It's useless, we showed you every possiblity already. Make a decision: If your values can exceed Float.MAX_VALUE move to double, if not keep float and cast your double values to float. I will not response here anymore got down voted, for all that effort.

Comment: You are telling to replace method but I have both requirements.

Comment: Then you have your answer! Move to double and all will be fine. float fits in double thats all! when passing a float value into a method with double signature its auto casted.

Comment: And I have to send both type of inputs

Comment: But if i use double, if i send small values as input(means float or int values) my memory will be wasted na